# Java error: class, interface, or enum expected,

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class box
{
   int h,w,d;
}

void volume()
{
   System.out.println("Volume="+(w*h*d));
}

class boxdemo
{
   public static void main(String arg[])
   {
      box b1=new box();
      box b2=new box();
      b1.h=10;
      b1.w=20;
      b1.d=30;
      b2.h=20;
      b2.w=30;
      b2.d=40;
      b1.volume;
      b2.volume;
   }
}
```

What's wrong with the code? please send me the correct code. It shows two errors saying class,interface or enum expected.

Comment: You `volume()` method is not a part of any class.

Answer (score 1):

All methods in Java (also called "functions" in some other languages) must be inside a class.

Because `volume` references members of `box` I therefore assume it is intended to belong to `box`.

```
class Box
{
    int h,w,d;

    void volume()
    {
        System.out.println("Volume="+(w*h*d));
    }
}
```

Notice that I also changed `box` to `Box` becauses classes in Java start with an uppercase letter by convention.

Furthermore, method calls in Java end with parentheses, even if they do not take arguments:

```
//       vv
b1.volume();
b2.volume();
```

Answer (score 0):

In above example your method is not inside of class so you must follow syntax of Class:

```
<class-modifiers> class <class name> <extends clause> <implements clause> {
//class body
    <variable declaration>
    <method declaration>
    <nested class declaration>
    <nested interface declaration>
    <constructor declaration>
    <initializer block (static block and instance block)>
}
```

And there is some java naming conventions which must be follow

- **Class, Interface, Enum** : Start with capital letter and processed with camelCase letter. Ex. BoxDemo
- **Method** : Start with small letter and processed with camelCase letter Ex. getValue(), setValue()
- **Variable** Start with small letter and processed with camelCase letter Ex. value, data, testValue.
- **Constant** All letter should be Uppercase letter. It can be separate with connecting characters like (underscore _) Ex. MIN_WIDTH

Only three types in java which have byte code which is

- Class
- Interface
- Enum

For details information go sun (oracle) java naming convention rule as
[sun java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

You code written as

```
class Box {
    int h, w, d;
    int volume;

    void volume() {
        volume = w * h * d;
        System.out.println("volume : " + volume);
    }
}

public class BoxDemo {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Box b1 = new Box();
        Box b2 = new Box();
        b1.h = 10;
        b1.w = 20;
        b1.d = 30;
        b2.h = 20;
        b2.w = 30;
        b2.d = 40;
        b1.volume();
        b2.volume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to learn more Java. You have some interesting links here: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

```
class Box{
 private int h,w,d;

 public Box(final int h, final int w, final int d){
   this.h = h;
   this.w = w;
   this.d = d;
 }

 public int volume(){
   return h * w *d;
 }
}
```

And you can use your Box

```
class Launcher{

   public static void main(String arg[]){
     final Box b1 = new Box(10,20,30);
     final Box b2 = new Box(20,30,40);

      System.out.println("Volume="+b1.volume());
      System.out.println("Volume="+b2.volume());
   }
}
```